# Parition a rectangle with a rectilinear hole in it, into mininal numbers of rectangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

I am aware that there are bunch of algorithm to deal with the hole-free polygons, however, my problem is a rectangle with a polygon hole. Are these two problems essentially the same?